# Custom ItemsControl and selection support

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to create a control that:

- derives from ItemsControl,
- can be bound to list of enums,
- for each enum it will display RadioButton,
- when given RadioButton is selected then SelectedItem will contain enumeration value associated with the RadioButton.

I have managed to achieve the first three points from the list above, but I have problems with the fourth item. I suspect it might be connected with either wrong implementation of item container class or wrong item template definition in generic.xaml.

Item container looks like this:

```
public class MyEnumSelectorItem : ContentControl
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty;

static MyEnumSelectorItem()
{
    IsSelectedProperty = Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyEnumSelectorItem));
}

public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
}

static readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Mode", typeof(MyEnum), typeof(MyEnumSelector), new PropertyMetadata());
public MyEnum Mode
{
    get { return (MyEnum)GetValue(ModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ModeProperty, value); }
}
}
```

The item container type is associated with the selector control (derives from `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector`) using `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride/GetContainerForItemOverride/PrepareContainerForItemOverride` method overrides.

The relevant fragment of generic.xaml looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyEnumSelector}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding}" 
                     IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     GroupName="enumSelector" Height="25" FontWeight="Bold"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The above assumes that correct binding of IsSelected property will automatically result in SelectedItem property to be set (which I hope is correct, isn't it?).

Comment: Shouldn't you be deriving from `Selector`? `SelectedItem` is defined on `Selector` and not `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Actually it derives from Selector (as indicated later in my question) - in the first sentence I meant that it should derive at least from ItemsControl.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that just calling `Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner` is not enough here.

Looking at `ListBoxItem`'s code in [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), you can see that several other things are possibly being done to synchronize between the selected item and the selector itself, like raising the Selected/Unselected event.

```
static ListBoxItem()
{
    ListBoxItem.IsSelectedProperty = Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(BooleanBoxes.FalseBox, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal, new PropertyChangedCallback(ListBoxItem.OnIsSelectedChanged)));
    ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent = Selector.SelectedEvent.AddOwner(typeof(ListBoxItem));
    ListBoxItem.UnselectedEvent = Selector.UnselectedEvent.AddOwner(typeof(ListBoxItem));
    ...
}

private static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = d as ListBoxItem;
    bool flag = (bool)e.NewValue;
    Selector parentSelector = listBoxItem.ParentSelector;
    if (parentSelector != null)
    {
        parentSelector.RaiseIsSelectedChangedAutomationEvent(listBoxItem, flag);
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        listBoxItem.OnSelected(new RoutedEventArgs(Selector.SelectedEvent, listBoxItem));
    }
    else
    {
        listBoxItem.OnUnselected(new RoutedEventArgs(Selector.UnselectedEvent, listBoxItem));
    }
    listBoxItem.UpdateVisualState();
}
```

I haven't tried it myself to see whether this actually solves the problem, but I think it's a good place to start. You should also consider having your items derive from `ListBoxItem` rather than `ContentControl`.

Comment: Just now I've tried deriving MyEnumSelectorItem from ListBoxItem and (as a separate attempt) adding the OnIsSelectedChanged callback - unfortunately no change (and the callback is not called).

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny If the callback isn't called (and you remembered to add it to the property's metadata), then there's a good chance there's something wrong with your binding. You should look for binding errors and make sure the value is actually being set.

Comment: Yes, it was added to property metadata, just as above. I have only now spotted the following error in Output window in VS: System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'object' ''MyEnum' (HashCode=4)'. BindingExpression:Path=IsSelected; DataItem='MyEnum' (HashCode=4); target element is 'RadioButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
It seems that my binding is referring to original enum and not to the container item (which are created as the debugger shows)... But how do I write the correct binding?

Comment: @TomaszGrobelny Try to use `TemplateBinding` rather than `Binding`

Comment: You mean like this: IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}"? This results in "error MC3011: Cannot find the static member 'IsSelectedProperty' on the type 'ContentPresenter'" during compilation.